# Import-Csv, alter 1 field, then export

Tags: powershell, csv

I have data (tab-delimited) in the following format:

```
Id      Dates                        Number
5       01-01-18<space><tab>         19
5       01-01-18 02-03-18            19
5       01-01-18 02-03-18 03-02-18   19
37      07-09-18                     19
37      07-09-18 07-15-18            19
37      07-09-18 07-15-18 07-28-18   18.1
41      03-15-18                     19
41      03-15-18 04-15-18            19
41      03-15-18 04-15-18 05-15-18   36.5
```

The second fields `Dates` is actually an array (space-delimited) with a trailing space.

I need to import this into PowerShell and export to a new CSV file after modifying the second field to only include the last date:

```
Id      Dates      Number
5       01-01-18   19
5       02-03-18   19
5       03-02-18   19
37      07-09-18   19
37      07-15-18   19
37      07-28-18   18.1
41      03-15-18   19
41      04-15-18   19
41      05-15-18   36.5
```

I haven't been able to get anything but errors after iterating through records (so I have no semi-working code to post along with this).

The CSV file can contain as many as 100,000 records.

---

So I've got this so far:

```
$ImportDir = "input_dir"
$ExportDir = "output_dir"

# We only want the files generated yesterday
$Date = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1).ToString('yyyyMMdd')

Add-Content ($ExportDir + "blahblah_" + $Date + ".txt") "Id`tDate`tValue"

Get-ChildItem $ImportDir -Filter *_blahblah_$Date.txt | ForEach-Object {
    $File = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText((Resolve-Path $_.FullName))

    foreach ($RecordSet In $File) {
        $RecordSet.TrimEnd() -Replace "(\d+?)`t.*(\d\d-\d\d-\d\d) `t(\d+?.\d+?) `t", "`$1`t`$2`t`$3" |
            #Select-Object -Skip 1 |
            Add-Content ($ExportDir + "blahblah_" + $Date + ".txt")
    }
}
```

I switched to using `[System.IO.File]` because it was faster than `-ReadCount` and `-ReadCount` was somehow losing records. Last bit I need to figure out with this is how to skip the first line of each file (basically I'm performing this regex on many files and need to remove the headers). Seems like anything I do causes the script to not work.

Comment: i was going to post using `Import-CSV` ... then i finally noticed the 100k records bit. ouch! this will parse the CSV import `$_.Dates.Trim().Split(' ')[-1]` and give you the last [or only] date _without_ the trailing space. ///// however, that won't work well with a large CSV file. you may need to use the `StreamReader` stuff to make that work. if so, then you will need to split the line on `<tab>`, take the 2nd part [index 1], and feed that into the parser above.

Comment: if your file is too big, keep your code within pipelines, so you don't have to worry about memory or using streamreader (it will not load entire file in memory). for example: cat test.csv | foreach {$d = $_.split("`t"); $d[0], $d[1].split(" ")[-1], $d[2] -join "," } | out-file new.csv

Comment: If you don't have semi-working code then post your non-working code (including the errors that code produces). Helping fix that is what SO is for. Not posting any code at all on the other hand usually isn't acceptable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to treat the data as straight text, and your CSV is indeed formatted just as you specified (no quotes or anything), then you could perform a regex replace on each line to get the data you want, and it should be relatively quick. I've got it processing 1000 records at a time, but you can try playing with the `-ReadCount` number to see if you can improve performance. Higher numbers use more memory, but should make it go faster.

```
ForEach($RecordSet in (Get-Content C:\Path\To\File.csv -ReadCount 1000)){
    $RecordSet -replace "(\S+?)`t.*(\d\d-\d\d-\d\d) `t(.*)$","`$1`t`$2`t`$3" | Add-Content C:\Path\To\NewFile.csv
}
```

Comment: Nice, but instead of the inner `Add-Content` you should use an outer `Set-Content`.

Comment: I love this method due to the speed and have implemented it into my script. I set the ReadCount to 5000 however it appears to drop the last X number of records past the last full 5000. For example if there are 92,397 records in a file, it will process the first 90,000 but the last 2,397 get lost.

Comment: @mklement0 Can't pipe out of a `ForEach`, so I'd have to wrap it, and that would slow things down I'm pretty sure. I was trying to avoid having a 100k line file read into memory at once. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Ryan.James Maybe you need to update your version of PowerShell? I am not able to replicate that behavior. I ran it on a file with 97345 lines, and got an output file with 97345 lines.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician: Oops! I missed that you're using a  `foreach` _statement_. Generally, you can pipe a `foreach` statement by enclosing it in `. { ... }`, but note that by using the `Get-Content` command inside a `foreach` statement you're invariably collecting the _entire_ file in memory anyway. A more memory-friendly alternative would be to pipe `Get-Content -ReadCount` to a `ForEach-Object` call, which you can then pipe to `Set-Content`.

Comment: Ah, ok. I had it backwards I guess. I thought I could get better memory performance out of the ForEach loop using it as I did. I tried wrapping and piping it with `$(ForEach(){})|Set-Content`, and ended up with the same performance as what I have already. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: Well, the `foreach` loop indeed boosts performance, but it reads the _entire_ file up front, so you might as well use `-ReadCount 0` to return a _single_ array comprising all lines. The same goes for `$(ForEach(){})|Set-Content`, because `$(...)` and `@(...)` - unlike `. { ... }` and `& { ... }` - _invariably_ collect all output up front. Even  `. { ... }` and `& { ... }` wouldn't help the read-everything-up-front behavior in this case, because the `Get-Content` call is used in the `foreach` _loop condition_, where it is again treated as an _expression_ that is fully evaluated up front.

Comment: In short: The only way to to retain the benefits of chunking without reading everything up front is to use: `Get-Content C:\Path\To\File.csv -ReadCount 1000 | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace "(\S+?)\`t.*(\d\d-\d\d-\d\d) \`t(.*)$", "\`$1\`t\`$2\`t\`$3" } | Set-Content C:\Path\To\NewFile.csv`

Answer (score 3):

even tho i think you will need to use `StreamReader` for a large file, here is how i would do it with `Import-CSV`. note that it's literally the last date in the column, not necessarily the chronological last date [*grin*] ...

```
# fake reading in a CSV file with tab delimiters
#    in real life, use Import-CSV
# each "Dates" column has a trailing <space>
$InStuff = @'
Id  Dates   Number
5   01-01-18    19
5   01-01-18 02-03-18   19
5   01-01-18 02-03-18 03-02-18  19
37  07-09-18    19
37  07-09-18 07-15-18   19
37  07-09-18 07-15-18 07-28-18  18.1
41  03-15-18    19
41  03-15-18 04-15-18   19
41  03-15-18 04-15-18 05-15-18  36.5
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter "`t"

$LastDateOnly = foreach ($IS_Item in $InStuff)
    {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        ID = $IS_Item.Id
        Date = $IS_Item.Dates.Trim().Split(' ')[-1]
        Number = $IS_Item.Number
        }
    }

$LastDateOnly
```

output ...

```
ID Date     Number
-- ----     ------
5  01-01-18 19    
5  02-03-18 19    
5  03-02-18 19    
37 07-09-18 19    
37 07-15-18 19    
37 07-28-18 18.1  
41 03-15-18 19    
41 04-15-18 19    
41 05-15-18 36.5
```

Comment: Note that the unary form of `-split` trims leading and trailing whitespace too, so you could more simply write: `(-split $IS_Item.Dates)[-1]`

Comment: @mklement0 - yep, but that is SO very non-obvious! [*grin*] i prefer to stick with something that is more-or-less self documenting - so that when i need to maintain it i can figure it out without needing to look it up ... and i would need to look it up. [*blush*]

Comment: Obviousness is in the eye of the beholder. For instance, it's equally non-obvious that `.Trim()` _without arguments_ trims _whitespace_. It's only obvious to you because you've used / seen it so frequently. Same goes for unary `-split`. Realizing the usefulness of a generally abstract construct helps with memory retention.

Comment: @mklement0 - i see your point ... but disagree about the obvious-ness. [*grin*] that `.Trim()` trims whitespace is admittedly somewhat less than clear. it still seems more apparent than the unary `-split` and it's odd behavior that has no discernable connection with splitting a string. [*grin*]

Comment: The unary form of `-split` emulates the venerable [`awk`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK) Unix utility's default field-splitting behavior. The utility of the behavior is in considering all runs of whitespace on a given line separators, so that only runs of non-whitespace chars. are considered fields.

Comment: @mklement0 - oh, it is _nifty_, but splitting on _groups_ of whitespace is unexpected. still, i agree that it is worth keeping in mind. thanks! [*grin*]